# What does Vaa mean?

Tags: power-supply, instrumentation-amplifier

[image: Circuit diagram]

I'm trying to understand this circuit. It looks like all the NCP chips are just voltage regulators, but I don't understand the VDD and VAA labeling, what do these mean.

Also, any idea why the top right and top left circuits are exactly the same but lead to different labels?

For reference, this power supply circuit is being used for a circuit that uses instrumentation amplifiers and an AD converter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably they've just separated analog (Vaa) and digital (Vdd) supplies by using two similar regulators, which is a valid way to keep digital noise out of the analog signals.